# Load Childhtml on list view

Tags: php, xml, local.xml, local

Inside our template/catalog/product/list.php file I want to load ChildHtml.

Inside list.php I got this line:

```
   <ul class="productbox-beknoptespecs">
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('beknopte_specificaties_new'); ?>
   </ul>
```

What do I need to place inside our local.xml file?

External .php file:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $theme = $this->helper('ultimo');
?>

<!-- LAPTOPS -->

<?php $yourCatIds = array(27,233,234,235);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();

if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {

    if($_product->getData('i_display_diagonal_944_1')) :
    echo '<li class="short-specifications"><span class="attributename">' . $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('i_display_diagonal_944_1')->getFrontendLabel() . '</span>';
    echo '<span class="attributetext">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_display_diagonal_944_1') . '</span></li>';
    endif;

}
?>
```

I tried this but that does not work:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
<reference name="product_list">
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="beknopte_specificaties_new" as="beknopte_specificaties_new" template="catalog/product/view/beknoptespecs.phtml"/>
</reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: Where are you defined  beknopte_specificaties_new in xml. `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('beknopte_specificaties_new'); ?>`

Comment: @AmitBera See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code by local.xml

```
<!--
Category default layout
-->

    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <reference name="product_list">
           <block type="Block_Prefix/BlockClass" name="beknopte_specificaties_new"  template="YouTemplateLocation/Yourfile.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

<!--
Category layered navigation layout
-->

    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <reference name="product_list">
           <block type="Block_Prefix/BlockClass" name="beknopte_specificaties_new"  template="YouTemplateLocation/Yourfile.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

**As per as  your update** :the block type `catalog/product_view`  is not working  as it product view page main content page.

Comment: Thanks Amit! Tried that code, but that does not display the file. Nothing is loaded.

Comment: I used this line `<block type="core/template" name="beknopte_specificaties_new" as="beknopte_specificaties_new" template="catalog/product/list/beknoptespecs_new.phtml"/>`. That does display the file, but it breaks down the page, because php can not be loaded

Comment: Please show the code of phtml

Comment: See the edit above

Comment: hi.. Jelle ,i guess that you got the answer for Marius http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67045/list-phtml-load-external-file-with-php-does-not-work-missing-helpers